# How to return array of data as return type in my linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

Below given are my classes. The return type of the class should be CpsResponse, but I dont know how to put things in my class return type. I am very new to the programming world.

```
  public class CpsResponse
    {

        private CustomerProfile[] customerProfileField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CustomerProfile")]
        public CustomerProfile[] CustomerProfile
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerProfileField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerProfileField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>

    public class CustomerProfile
    {

        private CustomerIdentifier customerIdentifierField;

        private string emailField;

        private string titleField;

        private string firstNameField;



        /// <remarks/>
        public CustomerIdentifier CustomerIdentifier
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerIdentifierField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerIdentifierField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return this.emailField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.emailField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return this.titleField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.titleField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.firstNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.firstNameField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>

    public class CustomerIdentifier
    {

        private string uniqueCustomerIdentifierField;

        private string versionField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string UniqueCustomerIdentifier
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uniqueCustomerIdentifierField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uniqueCustomerIdentifierField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.versionField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting values from db into the object ‘customerData’. Now I want to return the value and my return type should be CpsResponse. How can I achieve that?

```
var customerResult = (from a in customerData
                       select new CpsResponse {//what actually I should //write here I don’t know, Please help});
```

Please do the needful.

Comment: You should look into something called "auto-implemented properties". It will cut down your code significantly while achieving identical results.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Good point, however, you should add property initialization code to the constructor, unless you like null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the definition of your `CpsResponse` we cannot answer the question exactly, but basically it will look like:

```
List<CpsResponse> myList = (from a in customerdata
  select new CpsResonse { id = a.CustomerIdentifier, email = a.emailField }).ToList()
```

You do the select new and initalize the properties of your `CpsResponse` with the field you need from the DB.

Comment: just noticed you need an array, but the code is pretty similar in that case just use ToArray